# How to get text from input form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Input form: I can type random text and get the output in the console, like so: "getWeather.html?city=London:76"

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter City here..">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

javaScript:

```
var input = $('input')[0].form.city.value;
console.log(input);
```

However, I would like to get the input directly into a variable. In this case 'London'.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Isn't `input` a variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do - is your issue figuring out how to insert a query string in the URL into the value of the input? `input` is already a variable into which you can put the value of the input element...

Comment: I have a text field, in this case I type 'London' and hit enter OR the submit-button. With jQuery I fetch the value from the input form and save it in the 'input' variable (OK, sry that's confusing). The console.log gives "getWeather.html?city=London:76"

Comment: The `console.log` of what? So you want to get just "London" instead of "getWeather.html?city=London:76" in whatever you're console.logging?

Comment: Exactly, just the city.

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand, the way you are getting the city value is wrong. 
Here I'm using a JQuery selector with an attribute value lookup. The selector basicly says: Look for every input with the attribute `name` equals to `city`.

Then i'm using the `val()` function to get the value. I've added a `ev` paremeters which is the Javacript event and i have stopped it using `ev.preventDefault();`. This prevent the page from reloading.

To conclude, I've simply `console.log` the value.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var value = $('input[name=city]').val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter City here..">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Nikolas, that is exactly what I was looking for. It even works with jQuery 3.3.1. Also, thanks a lot for the great explanation. Cheers.

Comment: Glad I could help !